# How to set `invalidAttributeNamePrefix` value in Java?

Tags: htmlcleaner

Suppose I'm cleaning some html using [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net) ([v2.18](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner/htmlcleaner/2.18)) and I want to set the property `invalidAttributeNamePrefix` (see section [Cleaner parameters](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/parameters.php)) to some value, *i.e.:* `data-`.

This way an attribute `my-custom-attr="my-value"` in the HTML will be transformed to `data-my-custom-attr="my-value"`.

**How can I do that?** I wasn't able to find any example for the [Java usage](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php).

You can take as reference this piece of code:

```
HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
CleanerProperties properties = cleaner.getProperties();
properties.setOmitComments(true);
// properties.setInvalidAttributeNamePrefix("data-"); there is no such method

// html is a declared variable which contains some html content
TagNode rootTagNode = cleaner.clean(html);
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new PrettyXmlSerializer(properties);
String cleanedHtml = xmlSerializer.getAsString(rootTagNode);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to [version 2.22](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner/htmlcleaner/2.22) solves this.

Now it can be done

```
// ...
properties.setInvalidXmlAttributeNamePrefix("data-");
//...
```